# Docker container cannot use its host's /etc/hosts file

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, docker, sssd

After I joined some of my Ubuntu servers (mostly 20.02) to an AD domain(using realmd and sssd), they're unable to use their host's /etc/hosts file! Which they could do before they were a part of AD.

Has anyone ever faced anything like this before?
I really need to figure a solution out for this.

Appreciate your helpful answers.